# How to the get limit value when user passes Model.limit(10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when the user calls `Model.limit(10)` I want is get the value of 10.

So for that, I have overloaded a function

```
def visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement(o, collector)
    if o.limit
      limcoll = Arel::Collectors::SQLString.new
      visit o.limit, limcoll
       puts "#{limcoll}"
    end
end
```

This was working till Rails 4 but it was not working in Rails 6 (It prints ?)

I was trying to fix it for a long time but not succeeded.
Can anyone please help me? What is the mistake I am doing?